# Conversion from rectangular to hyperbolic coordinates not reversible

Tags: python

I was recently working on a module that contained a set of coordinate system conversions, and I ran into a problem when working with [hyperbolic coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_coordinates). By the definition given on Wikipedia, a hyperbolic coordinate `(u, v)` can be expressed in terms of cartesian coordinates as `u = -1/2ln(y/x)` where `ln` is the natural logarithm, and `v = sqrt(xy)`. The inverse of this being `x = ve^u` and `y = ve^-u` where `e` is Euler's constant.

Knowing that, take a look at these two functions I wrote to perform the conversion:

```
def rectangular_to_hyperbolic(coordinate):
    """
    Convert a rectangular (cartesian) coordinate to hyperbolic form.
    """
    x, y = coordinate
    u = -1/2*math.log1p(y/x)
    v = math.sqrt(x*y)
    return u, v

def hyperbolic_to_rectangular(coordinate):
    """
    Convert a hyperbolic coordinate to rectangular form.
    """
    u, v = coordinate
    x = v*(math.e**u)
    y = v*(math.e**-u)
    return x, y
```

It looks alright to me, so it shocked me when I got this output:

```
>>> hyperbolic_to_rectangular(rectangular_to_hyperbolic((5, 5)) 
(3.53553, 7.07107) # this should be (5, 5)
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`math.log1p(x)` is `ln(1+x)`, not `ln(x)`:

> log1p(x)
>
> Return the natural logarithm of 1+x (base e). The result is computed
>   in a way which is accurate for x near zero.

You probably want to use `math.log` instead.

Demo:

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: def r2h(c):
   ...:     x, y = c
   ...:     return -math.log(y/x), math.sqrt(x*y)
   ...:

In [3]: def h2r(c):
   ...:     u, v = c
   ...:     return v*math.exp(u), v*math.exp(-u)
   ...:

In [4]: h2r(r2h((5, 5)))
Out[4]: (5.0, 5.0)
```